# In android issues while getting geo locations using GPS

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I need some clarification regarding location tracing, i used the following code snippet to get the current user location, in my code i call the location listener with one minute delay. **each time i getting different location values**, i won't move/disturb the device, the device is kept on the table, i can't understand why it's happening, is there any issues in my code or i need to do some thing please guide me for this, Thanks in advance,

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) HomeActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                currentLatitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                currentLongitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                60000, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: How close are the different location values?

Comment: Are you in a closed area? If so tt may use the A-GPS function which provides you the cellular location data which may float. Did you set the permissions in manifest?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz: i got the values with maximum differences, so it will pointed first time in one street next time in another street but the device in same position.

Comment: @SergeyBenner: could you explain in detail which Permission i need to add,

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER

Comment: @SergeyBenner: Ya i added these, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

Comment: @Aerrow I am in same problem...please help me if you got the answer..

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for GPS:
 
The cooridnates expressed as double or float variable will have a resolution to some centimeters or millimeters.
But the effective accuracy is much lower:
With good view to sky, (outside) 10m often happen, up to 30m can happen.

Inside the office, your position will heavy move, up to 50-60m, and if you loose GPS and the phone switches to cell tower location, a movement up to 1000m can happen.

It depends on the GPS application, but each GPS Application has to filter the GPS locations
to its needs.

(GPS is more accurate when the device moves)

Comment: so you advised to enter the distance in my location listener right?

Comment: this would be th simplest solution, otherwise you have to developp your own distance filter. i dont know how good the distance filter in the listener woeks. i have weitten my own

Comment: @Aerrow if my answer helped, consoider upvoting and or accepting